# Attachment saved in variable with wp_mail() not being sent

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

After having read the documentation for wp_mail several times and looking around for solutions, i still haven't been able to figure out how to get a file attached with wp_mail();

First of all, i'm of the understanding that the file path is needed, but how do i know where it is saved on my wordpress site? And when it is is saved, is it temporary or permanently?

Currently i'm just using `$attachments = array(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip');`
because i saw it in another post on stackoverflow. But this means that i'm not using my `$_POST['file']`
 in which the path should be stored.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" role="form" action=''>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label>Navn</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"  required/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label>Tlf.</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="phone" type="tel" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label>Firma</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="company" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['company']; ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label>Besked</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" type="text" rows="6" required><?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary">
                        Vedhæft billeder&hellip; <input type="file" name="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12" id="checkrow">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" required> Jeg er et menneske
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 form-group" style="padding-top:1rem;">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width:5rem">
        </div>

        <?php echo $result; ?>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$to = "ch@ap-pe.dk";
$msg = "Navn: ".$_POST['name']."
        Email: ".$_POST['email']."
        Tlf: ".$_POST['phone']."
        Firma: ".$_POST['company']."
        Besked: ".$_POST['message'];
$msg = wordwrap($msg, 70);
$headers = 'From: ';
$attachments = array(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if (!$_POST['name']){
        $errorMsg="Indtast navn";
    }
        if (!$_POST['email']){
        $errorMsg.="Indtast email";
    }
        if (!$_POST['message']){
        $errorMsg.="Indtast besked";
    }
        if (!$_POST['check']){
        $errorMsg.="Bekræft at du er menneske";
    }

    $result = "Ret følgende fejl: $errorMsg";

    wp_mail($to, "Kontakt Besked",$msg, $headers, $attachments);



}
?>
```

Comment: Your task is sending email with attachment on form submit?

Comment: @stweb exactly!

Comment: You can use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)  function to move uploaded file to the path you specify.

Comment: PHPMailer includes [an example showing how to send uploaded files](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps). You should also read the PHP docs on handling file uploads, as it's easy to get something that "works" while being horribly unsafe.